# Scala - return empty Option if value contained in array

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm splitting an input of type Option[String] into an Option[Array[String]] as follows:

```
val input:Option[String] = Option("a=b,1000,what?")
val result: Option[Array[String]] = input map { _.split(",") }
```

I want to add a test whereby if any member of the array matches (eg, is an Long less than 0), the whole array is discarded and an empty Option returned.

Comment: so the type of `string` is not `String`? Please post something that compiles.

Comment: `map` on `String` expects a `Char => B`. But there's no `split` for `Char`. So this code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, it's an Option[String]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `filter` to perform a test on the content of an `Option`.
2. Use `exists` to check whether any member of the collection fullfils a condition.

---

```
result.filter(! _.exists(s => test(s)))
```

or

```
result.filterNot(_.exists(s => test(s)))
```

Comment: I think it should actually be `input map { _.split(",") } filter(! _.exists(s => test(s)))`, or (clearer?) `input map { _.split(",") } filter(_.forall(s => !test(s)))` , otherwise the result is only None if all the members of the array match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `find()` on the collection ? If it returns a `Some(x)`, then something has satisfied the condition.

```
list.find(_ < 0) match {
   case Some(x) => None
   case None => Some(list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you know that you can split and then filter as @ziggystar suggests, but if you have a really big `String`and an element at the beginning matches then it's pointless to finish splitting the string when you know it's going to be discarded.

In this case, if you're worried about time efficiency, you can use a `Stream` and re-implement the split operation, something like this:

```
def result(input:Option[String]):Option[Seq[String]] = {
  def split(c: Char, chars:Stream[Char]):Stream[String] = {
    val (head,tail) = chars span(_ != c)
    head.mkString #:: (if(tail isEmpty) Stream.empty else split(c, tail tail))
  }

  input map {s => split(',', Stream(s:_*)) } filter (_.forall (s => !test(s)))
}
```

Note that the map/filter structure stays the same, but it is now short-circuiting due to the use of `Stream`.

If it's a *really* big string you probably have it as a `Stream[Char]` already which means you don't even have the memory overhead of hanging on the original String.

Comment: If it's a really big string, `Stream` only helps you as long as you don't get towards the end somehow. Because once you need to look at the last element, the complete string will be held in memory by the `Stream` wrapper, together with an incredibly large amount of overhead, basically boxing each 1 byte `Char` in a 10+ byte wrapper. Yes, you can be very careful and make sure the beginning of the `Stream` get's gced. But I'd rather go for an `Iterator` in this case.

Comment: @ziggystar Fair point about space efficiency, but I don't see how you would make it work with an `Iterator` since checking the elements of the collection for a match on `test` would make them unavailable for further iteration?

Comment: Actually, I didn't think about the task at hand when answering. But anyway, there's `Iterator.buffered`, which returns a `BufferedIterator`, which let's you peek at the next element.